# I was here if you could meet me

Tags: tenses, past-vs-present

Is this correct or not. Recently I said this to a person and my brother in law suggested that it was wrong to say so. Instead I should have said
 I am here if you can meet me

Comment: The way you said it sounds like some kind of alternate universe / mystical. Stick to the present tense.

Comment: Wanted to create a sense of aura around myself:p)

Answer (score 1):

Your brother in law is correct. It am here if you could/can meet me.
"Am" is the current tense, "Was" is the past tense.
♥

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way to say this would be, "I am here. Can you come meet me?"

"I am here if you can meet me" is certainly understandable, but it is not entirely correct assuming you are at the meeting place. You are there whether or not they can meet you, so you would not need to say "if"; it would be more accurate to make a direct request.

Comment: I would say it's correct in the sense that if A could meet B, B is here. If not, it doesn't matter where B is, and B may not still be there if A were to change his mind and attempt to meet B anyways.

Comment: That is certainly true, although I look at it from the standpoint that the statement is in the present, and the condition where B may not be there in the future would only apply if the statement referred to the future. Here's an example: "I will be here if you can meet me."

Comment: The scenario was like I went to the person's place but the guard would not allow me in as I didn't have any appointment. He told me to call the person and take appointment at that moment. So I called him and then during the conversation I said this statement. I wanted to give an impression that I was around his place casually and not specially for meeting him. ( Even though my sole purpose was to meet him)

Comment: @Gerger So do you think the usage was correct??